# All users not visible after screen lock. Only logged in user is visible

Tags: login, xorg, screen, login-screen, logout

When i lock screen from top right pull down menu. I am not able to login into other users as rest of users are not visible. When I press ctrl alt f1 while logged in I sent to black screen with a cursor blinking and nothing happens , I have to force restart computer to get again to login to different user.Switch User, Logout, Lock Screen nothing works.